# "Unable to create message factory for SOAP" when migrate from servicemix 4.3.1 to 4.4.1

Tags: soap, apache-axis, apache-servicemix

I have a good working bundle: some cxf endpoints and some camel routes. 
I works excellently with servicemix 4.3.1
Below is a typical cxf:endpoint:

```
 <cxf:cxfEndpoint id="adapter.Service"
                 serviceName="tns:Service"
                 wsdlURL="etc/transfer.wsdl">
    <cxf:properties>
        <entry key="dataFormat" value="PAYLOAD"/>
        <entry key="ws-security.ut.no-callbacks" value="true"/>
    </cxf:properties>
    <cxf:inInterceptors>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor">
            <constructor-arg>
                <map>
                    <entry key="action" value="UsernameToken"/>
                    <entry key="passwordType" value="PasswordText"/>
                </map>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
        <ref bean="authenticationInterceptor"/>
    </cxf:inInterceptors>
</cxf:cxfEndpoint>
```

But when I try to deploy bundle to servicemix 4.3.1 I get next exception:

```
Unable to create message factory for SOAP: Provider org.apache.axis2.saaj.MessageFactoryImpl not found
```

Root of trouble: interceptors that provides security. 
If endpoint deployed without tags `<cxf:inInterceptors>` - all works good.
Is using in/out interceptors in 4.4.1 was changed ?
Is somebody have same troubles ?